# Скрипт выполняется только для первого идентификатора

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии на кнопку должна была появляется фотка и текст в инпут поле, но скрипт применяется только к первой кнопке.Я искал в интернете но не смог разобраться.
Сам код:

```js
document.getElementById('choose').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var l = document.createElement('img');
  var value = $("#choose").val();
  l.src = 'images/'+ value +'.png';
  document.body.appendChild(l);
});

$('body').on('click','#choose',function(){
    var textField = $('#send-input');
    var value = $("#choose").val();
    textField.val(textField.val() + '[' + value + ']') ;      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="send">
  <input type="text" id='send-input'>
</form> 
<button id = "choose" value = "beach" >beach</button>
<button id = "choose" value = "forest" >forest</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//document.getElementById('choose').addEventListener('click', function() {
//  ...
//});

$('body').on('click','#choose',function(){
    var textField = $('#send-input');
    var value = $(this).val();
                  ^^^^
    textField.val(textField.val() + '[' + value + ']') ;      

    var l = document.createElement('img');
    l.src = 'images/'+ value +'.png';
    document.body.appendChild(l);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Можете пожалуйста подсказать что надо сделать, чтобы картинки тоже появлялись по порядку.

Comment: @amir2799 Пожалуйста. Создание картинки у Вас в коде было правильно. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Спааасибо! Вы меня выручили!!!